# Rails 7, React & Esbuild - Static assets not served in production

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, esbuild

I have created a simple new Rails 7 project from scratch with Esbuild and React to get to know these, and they indeed feel like a step up from Webpack, except I can't manage to have my static files (ie image) served in production.

I have an Esbuild config file:

```js
// esbuild.config.js

const path = require('path');

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["application.jsx"],
  bundle: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  publicPath: "assets",
  sourcemap: true,
  watch: process.argv.includes('--watch'),
  plugins: [],
  loader: {
    '.js': 'jsx',
    '.jpg': 'file',
    '.png': 'file',
    '.MOV': 'file'
  },
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

I store my images in the `app/javascript/images/` folder, and import and use them in a React component like that (for example):

```js
import MyImage from "./images/myimage.jpg"
import styled from "styled-components";
//...

const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${MyImage});    
`
```

In development, everything works fine, Esbuild copies the images in the `app/assets/builds/` folder, fingerprints them, and prepends all the images url with the `publicPath` property of my Esbuild config. The above image for example then has the relative url `assets/myimage-FINGERPRINT.jpg` which is served correctly in development.

Then things get complicated in production (production here being just a Docker container built for production - I don't add the `Dockerfile` to keep things simple as I don't think it would help, but happy to provide it of course).

In my `production.rb` I have added the following:

```rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

(which will be replaced by an environment variable later)

The assets precompiling succeeds, and my images are in the `app/public/assets/` folder, fingerprinted once more by Sprockets this time (from what I understand), but now I get 404. I have tried changing Esbuild `publicPath` and have tried to get the images directly in my browser, but whatever I try (`assets`, `public`, `public/assets`), nothing work and I am running out of ideas.

I have temporary fix which is to change the loader for images to `dataurl`, but that does not feel like a good practice, as my compiled javascript is going to explode.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, and by looking at the answers to https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/76 and this PR: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/pull/726/files

I was able to figure out the proper setup that works.
in the `build` options, I changed

```js
publicPath: "assets",
```

to

```js
publicPath: "/assets",
```

(included the leading `/`, which was missing before and causing the wrong path to be used)

and then added the following option

```js
assetNames: "[name]-[hash].digested",
```

which, as you might be able to tell from the linked PR, would prevent Sprockets from adding an additional layer of fingerprinting.

I hope that helps.